# Android- Stuck with Running Project

Tags: java, android, android-emulator

I'm Developing an Android Application for the Tablet Devices . When I run My I mostly get an Error in the console which is given below

```
[2013-03-15 15:52:01 - Gprs] Failed to install Gprs.apk on device 'emulator-5554!
[2013-03-15 15:52:01 - Gprs] (null)
[2013-03-15 15:52:01 - Gprs] Launch canceled!
```

Comment: and you seriously searched and found nothing? I doubt that... check the right side for "related" ->

Answer (score 2):

**I think any one of the following alternatives will work:**

1. Try to chang the ADB connection timeout. I think the default is **5000ms** and we need to change       this to **10000ms** to get rid of the problem. If you are in Eclipse, you can do this by going through Window -> Preferences and then it is in DDMS under Android.
2. Restart the device.
3. Increase SD card volume and max VM app heap size. For this edit the virtual device and do the modifications. Any change of emulator parameters and its rebuilding also fine.
4. Build the application. Then Install the apk using command prompt.
   adb install

Answer (score 0):

You can try these steps:
Try changing the ADB connection timeout. If you are in Eclipse, you can do this by going through Window -> Preferences and then it is in DDMS under Android. Default is 5sec, try making it 10 seconds.

If this doesn't works restart your device

Or try,

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
```

command from command-line.

Comment: In command prompt after which path I need to give this command

Comment: @RakeshL set path in your environmental variables to `your-sdk/platform-tools`, then adb command will work

Answer (score 0):

Try to change  the **ADB connection timeout**.

Default - 5000ms

Change it to 10000ms

If you are in Eclipse, you can do this by going through **Window -> Preferences** and then it is in **DDMS under Android**.